# Arc length definition: integral vs partition

Tags: riemannian-geometry, smooth-manifolds, arc-length

Let $M$ be a connected Riemannian manifold. Let $\alpha:[a,b]\to M$ be a piecewise smooth curve segment. Then the arc length of $\alpha$ is defined as
\begin{equation}
    L(\alpha)=\int_a^b|\alpha'(t)|\,dt\text.
\end{equation}
The Riemannian distance function on $M$ is defined as
\begin{equation}
    d(p,q)=\inf\{L(\gamma):\text{$\gamma$ is a piecewise smooth curve segment from $p$ to $q$}\}\text.
\end{equation}
In any metric space $X$, the arc length of a (continuous) curve $\alpha:[a,b]\to X$ is defined as
\begin{equation}
    |\alpha|=\sup\left\{\sum_{i=1}^md(\alpha(s_{i-1}),\alpha(s_i)):a=s_0<\cdots<s_m=b\right\}\text.
\end{equation}

Is $L(\alpha)=|\alpha|$? I proved that $L(\alpha)\geq|\alpha|$, but could not prove the opposite inequality.

Comment: Are you able to do this when $M$ is $\mathbb{R}^n$ with the standard flat metric? I think a proof or even just an understanding of the challenge for that case is enlightening. It seems to me that the essential challenge is finding sufficient conditions for an upper bound of the length of a curve segement joining two points in terms of the shortest geodesic segment.

Answer (score 0):

To prove that $\alpha \le L(\alpha)$ it suffices to prove for each partition $0=s_0<s_1<\cdots<s_m=1$ that
$$\sum_{i=1}^md(\alpha(s_{i-1}),\alpha(s_i)) \le L(\alpha)
$$
because then the supremum of all of the left hand sides is also $\le L(\alpha)$.

Using the equation
$$L(\alpha) = \sum_{i=1}^m \int_{s_{i-1}}^{s_i} |a'(t)| \, dt
$$
and it therefore suffices to prove for each $i$ that
$$d(\alpha(s_{i-1}),\alpha(s_i)) \le \int_{s_{i-1}}^{s_i} |a'(t)| \, dt 
$$

Finally, using the inequality
$$\biggl| \int_{s_{i-1}}^{s_i} a'(t) \, dt \biggr| \le \int_{s_{i-1}}^{s_i} |a'(t)| \, dt 
$$
it suffices to prove that
$$d(\alpha(s_{i-1}),\alpha(s_i)) \le \biggl| \int_{s_{i-1}}^{s_i} a'(t) \, dt \biggr|
$$
which is true, in fact the two sides are equal, because both sides are equal to $|\alpha(s_{i}) - \alpha(s_{i-1})|$.

Comment: I'm unsure about your very last argument: how do you make sense of $|\alpha(s_i)-\alpha(s_{i_1})|$ on a Riemannian manifold? Or even of $\int \alpha'$?

Comment: Skip the last five lines. The inequality on $d$ is immediate because  of its definition as the inf of path lengths.

Comment: Ah, oops, I misread and thought this was about Euclidean space.

Comment: In which case, of course, yeah @TedShifrin

Comment: It is a late comment, but I need the opposite inequality.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an argument for smooth curves $\alpha$. The piecewise smooth case follows easily. At any point $x_0 = \alpha(s_0)$ on the curve, smoothness implies that $\alpha$ is locally tangent to the geodesic. In particular, for every $\epsilon > 0$ there exists $\delta > 0$ such that
$$
\left |\int_{s_0}^{s_1} |\alpha'(t)| \, dt \right| \le (1+\epsilon) d(\alpha(s_0), \alpha(s_1))
$$
whenever $|s_0-s_1| < \delta$. (I.e., the length of the segment of $\alpha$ from $t=s_0$ to $t=s_1$ does not exceed the geodesic distance by more than a factor of $1+\epsilon$.) A priori, $\delta$ will depend on both $s_0$ and $\epsilon$, but compactness implies that one can choose it independently of $s_0$. Now for any choice of partition $a=s_0< \ldots< s_n = b$ such that $s_i-s_{i-1}<\delta$ for all $i$, you get that the sum in the definition of $|\alpha|$ is $\ge \frac{L(\alpha)}{1+\epsilon}$, and letting $\epsilon$ go to zero, you get your desired inequality.

Details for this argument should not be too hard to fill in, assuming that $\alpha$ and the metric are at least continuously differentiable.

Comment: Can you explain more on how to get $\left|\int_{s_0}^{s_1}|\alpha'(t)|\,dt\right|\leq(1+\epsilon)d(\alpha(s_0),\alpha(s_1))$? I do not understand what locally tangent means.

Comment: I just meant that the curve $\alpha$ and the local geodesic at $x_0=\alpha(s_0)$ in the direction of $\alpha'(s_0)$ are both smooth with the same tangent vector at $x_0$, so that the distance of these curves is a $o(|s_0-s_1|)$. And then you get the inequality by continuity of the metric tensor. I'll try to add more details if I can find the time.